# Solve a classical theorem using a more advanced machinery.

Tags: real-analysis

My goal this time is to prove the classical theorem that states the following:

Let $f_n\in C^1([0,1])$ and $g\in C([0,1])$ such that

1) $(f_n(x_0))$ converges for some $x_0$

2) $f_n' \rightrightarrows g$

Then $f_n$ converges uniformly and, if $f_n\rightrightarrows f$, then $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and $f'=g$.

And then the references say that this theorem is really easy to prove if you have the following result:

Let $\mathcal I:C([0,1]\to C([0,1])$ be the operator given by

$$\displaystyle \mathcal If(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$

i.e. $\mathcal If$ is the undefined integral of $f$. Then $\mathcal I$ is continuous with respect to the uniform norm.

Then for the latter I approach it as follows:

We know that $\mathcal I$ is linear because it follows from the linearity of the integral, therefore:

$$||\mathcal If||_{u}=max_{x}(\int_0^x f(t) dt)<max_{x}(\int_0^x max_{t}(f(t)) dt)=x max_{t}(f(t))<max_{t}(f(t))=||f(t)||_{u}$$

And well, we have seen a theorem that says that if we have a linear transformation between two normed spaces $X,Y$ then it is continous if there exists a $M>0$ such that for all $x \in X$ $||\phi(x)||_{Y}<M||x||_{X}$

So my questions are, Am I right in my answer? and What can be done to get the classical result once we know that $\mathcal I$ is continous?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For (1): You are almost, but you have to insert a few $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\cdot}$-signs: Note that 
$$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{If} = \max_x \abs{\int_0^x f(t)\, dt} $$
and $\norm f = \max_t \abs{f(t)}$. You also have to replace the $<$ by $\le$. But the argument itself is correct.

For (2): Knowing that $I$ is continuous let's us argue as follows: As $f_n' \to g$ (uniformly, that is with respect to the uniform norm), and $I$ is continuous, we have $If_n' \to Ig$ (uniformly). Now $If_n' = f_n - f_n(0)$, as $f_n(x_0)$ converges, $f_n(0)$ also does, since
$$ f_n(0) = f_n(x_0) - (If_n')(x_0) $$
say $f_n(0) \to \alpha$. Now we can conclude that 
$$ f_n = If_n' + f_n(0) \to Ig + \alpha \text{  (uniformly)}. $$
Now let $f := Ig + \alpha$, then $f' = (Ig)' = g$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) for your help, just give a while to edit my post :), and If I have a doubt about your procedure, Can I let you know ?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure you can let me know.